# pip install conda==4.2.7 gives error on Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, installation, conda

Python version : Python 3.6.5
pip version : pip 9.0.1
Please help in installing coda using pip. 
Is this the best practice ?

pip install conda gave me this error : 
Collecting menuinst (from conda)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda) (from versions: )

so according to forums i tried to resolve it using: 
pip install conda==4.2.7

which resulted into following error:

Collecting conda==4.2.7
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/7c/374bc72a16f71b51aaad570192438b9752604121dfea4cb0abc5d0b2c2ca/conda-4.2.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "C:\Users\P2858687\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vh2vzjt0\conda\setup.py", line 32, in 
        from conda._vendor.auxlib import packaging  # NOQA
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auxlib'

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\P2858687\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vh2vzjt0\conda\
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: upgrading python or setup files both did not solve the issue.

Comment: You cannot install conda with pip. conda is installed via installers from anaconda.com.

Comment: Thank you ! that worked.